# Dynamic LINQ GroupBy Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I need to translate the following LINQ query to Dynamic LINQ that accepts several grouping columns based on user input. Basically I have a bunch of dropdownlists that apply groupings and I don't want to enumerate every combination of groupings. If Dynamic LINQ fails, I may have to construct a SQL query manually, and nobody wants that.

```
var grouping = ( from entry in ObjectContext.OmniturePageModules
    where entry.StartOfWeek >= startDate && entry.StartOfWeek <= endDate &&
        ( section == "Total" || section == "All" || entry.Section == section ) &&
        ( page == "Total" || page == "All" || entry.Page == page ) &&
        ( module == "Total" || module == "All" || entry.Module == module ) 
    group entry by new
    {
        entry.Page, // I want to be able to tell this anonymous type
        entry.Module, // which columns to group by
        entry.StartOfWeek // at runtime
    }
    into entryGroup
    select new
    {
        SeriesName = section + ":" + entryGroup.Key.Page + ":" + entryGroup.Key.Module,
        Week = entryGroup.Key.StartOfWeek,
        Clicks = entryGroup.Sum( p => p.Clicks )
    } );
```

I have no clue how to do this as Dynamic LINQ is totally undocumented outside of the "hello world!" select/where/orderby cases. I just can't figure out the syntax.

Something like:(?)

```
var grouping = ObjectContext.OmniturePageModules.Where(entry => entry.StartOfWeek >= startDate && entry.StartOfWeek <= endDate &&
                                           ( section == "Total" || section == "All" || entry.Section == section ) &&
                                           ( page == "Total" || page == "All" || entry.Page == page ) &&
                                           ( module == "Total" || module == "All" || entry.Module == module ))
                                           .GroupBy("new (StartOfWeek,Page,Module)", "it")
                                           .Select("new (Sum(Clicks) as Clicks, SeriesName = section + key.Page + Key.Module, Week = it.Key.StartOfWeek)");
```

I'm using the DynamicQueryable class in System.Linq.Dynamic. See: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Follow-up: 
Enigmativity's solution worked *mostly*. For some reason it doesn't want to group by the datetime "StartOfWeek" column -- workaround is just to do a secondary grouping:

```
var entries = ( from entry in ObjectContext.OmniturePageModules
                            where entry.StartOfWeek >= startDate
                                && entry.StartOfWeek <= endDate
                                && ( section == "Total" || section == "All" || entry.Section == section )
                                && ( page == "Total" || page == "All" || entry.Page == page )
                                && ( module == "Total" || module == "All" || entry.Module == module )
                            select entry ).ToArray(); // Force query execution

            var grouping = from entry in entries
                            let grouper = new EntryGrouper( entry, section, page, module )
                            group entry by grouper into entryGroup
                            select new
                            {
                                entryGroup.Key.SeriesName,
                                entryGroup.Key.Date, 
                                Clicks = entryGroup.Sum( p => p.Clicks ),
                            };

            var grouping2 = (from groups in grouping
                            group groups by new {groups.SeriesName, groups.Date } into entryGroup
                            select new
                            {
                               entryGroup.Key.SeriesName,
                               entryGroup.Key.Date,
                               Clicks = entryGroup.Sum( p => p.Clicks ),
                            } );
```

but this seems to seriously degrade performance... =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you explicitly want to use the LINQ Dynamic Query Library then my answer isn't going to be what you want, but if you want your desired behaviour and you're happy to use regular LINQ then I think I can help.

Essentially I've created an `EntryGrouper` class that handles the logic of grouping by the selected values in the dropdown lists and I've assumed that the variables `section`, `page` & `module` hold those values. I've also assumed that `ObjectContext.OmniturePageModules` is an enumerable of type `Entry`.

So your LINQ query now becomes these two:

```
var entries = (from entry in ObjectContext.OmniturePageModules
               where entry.StartOfWeek >= startDate
                   && entry.StartOfWeek <= endDate
                   && (section == "Total" || section == "All" || entry.Section == section)
                   && (page == "Total" || page == "All" || entry.Page == page)
                   && (module == "Total" || module == "All" || entry.Module == module)
               select entry).ToArray(); // Force query execution

var grouping = from entry in entries
               let grouper = new EntryGrouper(entry, section, page, module)
               group entry by grouper into entryGroup
               select new
               {
                   SeriesName = entryGroup.Key.SeriesName,
                   Week = entryGroup.Key.StartOfWeek,
                   Clicks = entryGroup.Sum(p => p.Clicks),
               };
```

The first query is used to force a simple select query on the database and return only the records that you want to group. Generally `group by` queries call the database multiple times so querying in this way is usually much faster.

The second query groups the results of the first query by creating instances of the `EntryGrouper` class as the grouping key.

I've included a `SeriesName` property in the `EntryGrouper` class so that all of the grouping logic is neatly defined in one place.

Now, the `EntryGrouper` class is quite large as, to allow grouping to work, it needs to have properties for `StartOfWeek`, `Section`, `Page` & `Module`, and contain overloads of the `Equals` & `GetHashCode` methods, and implement the `IEquatable<Entry>` interface.

Here it is:

```
public class EntryGrouper : IEquatable<Entry>
{
    private Entry _entry;
    private string _section;
    private string _page;
    private string _module;

    public EntryGrouper(Entry entry, string section, string page, string module)
    {
        _entry = entry;
        _section = section;
        _page = page;
        _module = module;
    }

    public string SeriesName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", this.Section, this.Page, this.Module);
        }
    }

    public DateTime StartOfWeek
    {
        get
        {
            return _entry.StartOfWeek;
        }
    }

    public string Section
    {
        get
        {
            if (_section == "Total" || _section == "All")
                return _section;
            return _entry.Section;
        }
    }

    public string Page
    {
        get
        {
            if (_page == "Total" || _page == "All")
                return _page;
            return _entry.Page;
        }
    }

    public string Module
    {
        get
        {
            if (_module == "Total" || _module == "All")
                return _module;
            return _entry.Module;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is Entry)
            return this.Equals((Entry)other);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Entry other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.Equals(this.StartOfWeek, other.StartOfWeek))
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(this.Section, other.Section))
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(this.Page, other.Page))
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(this.Module, other.Module))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.GetHashCode(this.StartOfWeek);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Section);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Page);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Module);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var template = "{{ StartOfWeek = {0}, Section = {1}, Page = {2}, Module = {3} }}";
        return String.Format(template, this.StartOfWeek, this.Section, this.Page, this.Module);
    }
}
```

The grouping logic of this class looks simply like this:

```
if (_page == "Total" || _page == "All")
    return _page;
return _entry.Page;
```

If I have misunderstood how you the dropdown values turn grouping on and off then you should just need to change these methods, but the crux of this code is that when grouping is on it should return a group value based on the value in the entry and otherwise it should return a common value for all entries. If the value is common for all entries then it logically only creates a single group which is the same as not grouping at all.

If you have more dropdowns that you're grouping by then you need to add more properties to the `EntryGrouper` class. Don't forget to add these new properties to the `Equals` & `GetHashCode` methods too.

This logic, therefore, represents the dynamic grouping that you wanted. Please let me know if I've helped or if you need more detail.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. I'll try this tomorrow and let you know if it works for me -- a quick glance over it is encouraging.

Comment: This doesn't seem to group by StartOfWeek for some reason. I had to change the grouping code for each column to if( _section == "All" )
                        return _entry.Section;
                    return _section;

Comment: @`Daniel Coffman` - I don't know why it hasn't grouped by `StartOfWeek`, it should have. I rechecked the code and the `Equals` & `GetHashCode` methods use the `StartOfWeek` value. Give me a yell if you'd like me to look into it further. I had expected the grouping code for each column would probably need to be "tweaked" a bit for your needs.

Answer (score 9):

Here it is in Dynamic LINQ -- of course you build the GroupBy and Select strings at runtime:

```
var double_grouping = ( ObjectContext.OmniturePageModules.Where( entry => entry.StartOfWeek >= startDate
                     && entry.StartOfWeek <= endDate
                     && ( section == "Total" || section == "All" || entry.Section == section )
                     && ( page == "Total" || page == "All" || entry.Page == page )
                     && ( module == "Total" || module == "All" || entry.Module == module ) )
                     .GroupBy( "new ( it.Section, it.Page, it.StartOfWeek )", "it" ) )
                     .Select( "new ( Sum(Clicks) as Clicks, Key.Section as SeriesSection, Key.Page as SeriesPage, Key.StartOfWeek as Week )" );
```

And here is the normal LINQ way that escaped me until a coworker pointed it out -- this is basically Enigmativity's solution without the grouper class:

```
var grouping = ( from entry in ObjectContext.OmniturePageModules
    where entry.StartOfWeek >= startDate && entry.StartOfWeek <= endDate &&
        ( section == "Total" || section == "All" || entry.Section == section ) &&
        ( page == "Total" || page == "All" || entry.Page == page ) &&
        ( module == "Total" || module == "All" || entry.Module == module )
    group entry by new
    {
        Section = section == "All" ? entry.Section : section,
        Page = page == "All" ? entry.Page : page,
        Module = module == "All" ? entry.Module : module,
        entry.StartOfWeek
    }
        into entryGroup
        select new
        {
            SeriesName =
            entryGroup.Key.Section + ":" + entryGroup.Key.Page + ":" + entryGroup.Key.Module,
            Week = entryGroup.Key.StartOfWeek,
            Clicks = entryGroup.Sum( p => p.Clicks )
        } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this question was posted but I had to deal with a similar problem recently (dynamic grouping by multiple columns selected by user in runtime) so here's my take on it.

1. Helper function for creating grouping lambdas

   ```
   static Expression<Func<T, Object>> GetGroupBy<T>( string property )
   {
     var data = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ), "data" );
     var dataProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField( data, property );
     var conversion = Expression.Convert( dataProperty, typeof( object ) );
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Object>>( conversion, data );
   }
   ```
2. Function for doing the in-memory grouping. Returns groups.

   ```
   static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Group<T>( IEnumerable<T> ds, params Func<T, object>[] groupSelectors )
   {
     Func<IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, object>[], IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> inner = null;
     inner = ( d, ss ) => {
       if ( null == ss || ss.Length == 0 ) {
         return new[] { d };
       } else {
         var s = ss.First();
         return d.GroupBy( s ).Select( g => inner( g.Select( x => x ), ss.Skip( 1 ).ToArray() ) ) .SelectMany( x => x );
       }
     };
     return inner( ds, groupSelectors );
   }
   ```
3. How would it be used:

   ```
   String[] columnsSelectedByUser = ... // contains names of grouping columns selected by user
   var entries = ... // Force query execution i.e. fetch all data
   var groupBys = columnsSelectedByUser.Select( x => GetGroupBy( x ).Compile()).ToArray();
   var grouping = Group(entries, groupBys); // enumerable containing groups of entries
   ```

Regarding degrading performances, I don't think that's actually a (big) problem. Even if you constructed a grouping SQL dynamically, the query would have to return the same number of rows as a query without the grouping. So although in this approach the grouping is not done by the database, the number of rows returned by forced query execution is the same as it would be for the hypothetical SQL query with grouping criteria. Sure, database would probably outperform in-memory grouping done by the C# code but the amount of traffic depends solely on how many rows (`entries`) have to be grouped.