# How to group by multiple generic linq expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm trying to use Linq expressions to construct a query, and am stuck trying to group by multiple columns.  Say I have a basic collection:

```
IEnumerable<Row> collection = new Row[]
{
    new Row() { Col1 = "a", Col2="x" },
    new Row() { Col1 = "a", Col2="x" },
    new Row() { Col1 = "a", Col2="y" },
};
```

I know you can group these using lambda expressions:

```
foreach (var grp in collection.GroupBy(item => new { item.Col1, item.Col2 }))
{
    Debug.Write("Grouping by " + grp.Key.Col1 + " and " + grp.Key.Col2 + ": ");
    Debug.WriteLine(grp.Count() + " rows");
}
```

This groups correctly as you can see:

```
Grouping by a and x: 2 rows
Grouping by a and y: 1 rows
```

But now, say I receive a collection of selectors to group against, that is passed to me as a parameter in my method, and that the entity type is generic:

```
void doLinq<T>(params Expression<Func<T,object>>[] selectors)
{
    // linq stuff
}
```

Whoever's invoking the method would call like this:

```
doLinq<Row>(entity=>entity.Col1, entity=>entity.Col2);
```

How would I construct the group-by expression?

```
foreach (var grp in collection.GroupBy(
      item => new { 
          // selectors??
      }))
{
    // grp.Key. ??
}
```

**Edit**

I updated above to hopefully clarify why I need the set of selectors.

**Edit #2**

Made the entity type in *doLinq* generic.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to write a function that combines the several `Expression<Func<Row,object>>` into a single `Expression<Func<Row,object>>` that returns a tuple or an array of values or whatever.  It looks like you're using linq to sql, and I don't know enough about the translation to sql to know whether you could do this in a translatable way, however.

Comment: @phoog it does seem like you should be able to combine them into a single expression-- I still don't know how to do that.  I ended up combining the results of the expressions instead, for each row.

Comment: You should post your solution as a new answer, not edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution worked for me.  It involves two parts:

- create a grouping object (which I implemented inelegantly as object[]) given the row value and the set of selectors.  This involves a lambda expression that compiles and invokes each selector on the row item.
- implement IEquality for the grouping object type (in my case that's IEqualityComparer).

*First part*

```
foreach (System.Linq.IGrouping<object[], T> g in collection.GroupBy(
    new Func<T, object[]>(
        item => selectors.Select(sel => sel.Compile().Invoke(item)).ToArray()
    ),
    new ColumnComparer()
)
{ ... }
```

*Second Part*

```
public class ColumnComparer : IEqualityComparer<object[]>
{
    public bool Equals(object[] x, object[] y)
    {
        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object[] obj)
    {
        return (string.Join("", obj.ToArray())).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This works for basic Linq, and Linq for the MySql connector.  Which other Linq providers, and which expression types this works for is a whole other question ...

Comment: I think this will query the database for all rows, then perform the grouping locally. So this will not work for linq-to-sql with a ms-sql server where the query is translated to t-sql, you would need an expression tree for that. Still, even in linq-to-sql you could always prepend .AsEnumerable() before your GroupBy() to force executing the grouping locally

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'll assume you use linq-to-sql or something similar, so you need expression trees. If not there might be other possibilities.

Possible solutions I can see:

- dynamic linq

see Vladimir Perevalovs answer.

- constructing the whole groupby expression-tree manually

see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

- ugly workaround

Well, that's my departement :)

untested code:

```
 void doLinq(params string[] selectors) // checking two expressions for equality is messy, so I used strings
     foreach (var grp in collection.GroupBy(
          item => new { 
              Col1 = (selectors.Contains("Col1") ? item.Col1 : String.Empty),
              Col2 = (selectors.Contains("Col2") ? item.Col2 : String.Empty)
              // need to add a line for each column :(
          }))
     {
          string[] grouping = (new string[]{grp.Key.Col1, grp.Key.Col2 /*, ...*/ }).Where(s=>!s.IsNullOrEmpty()).ToArray();
          Debug.Write("Grouping by " + String.Join(" and ", grouping)+ ": ");
          Debug.WriteLine(grp.Count() + " rows");
     }
 }
```

Comment: I realized I simplified the question too much at first- it obscured what I was trying to do.  The type "Row" is actually generic (see update above), which would seem to rule out #1 and #3.  #2 looks very interesting, I'm checking it out ...

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Dynamic Linq: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2008/02/07/linq-groupbymany-dynamically.aspx

Comment: Very interesting and useful link, but it's not quite what I want.  Mitsu is doing sub-groupings in a hierarchical relationship, but each grouping is done on a single key-- ie, group by countries, then for each group, group by cities.  I want to have a single level of grouping, but multiple properties in the key, eg, group by country and age bracket (Col1 and Col2 in my example).

Comment: Sorry I missed the target :) Here's a link similar question with what I meant as a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929041/dynamic-linq-groupby-multiple-columns  By Dynamic Linq I suggested using string based linq interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have extremely limited knowledge of linq-to-sql, but is it really important what's inside GroupBy? Because if it is not, you can roll out your own keySelector. Anyway, I tried it with both Sql Server CE  and Sql Server Express and this seems to work:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Props {
        public List<object> list = new List<object>();
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list, (obj as Props).list);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return list.Select(o => o.GetHashCode()).Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1 ^ i2);
        }
    }
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Lol db = new Lol(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Lol;Integrated Security=true");
            db.Log = Console.Out;
            doLinq(db.Test, row => row.Col1, row => row.Col2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void doLinq<T>(Table<T> table, params Func<T, object>[] selectors) where T : class {
            Func<T, Props> selector = item => {
                var props = new Props();
                foreach (var sel in selectors) props.list.Add(sel(item));
                return props;
            };
            foreach (var grp in table.GroupBy(selector)) {
                Console.Write("Grouping by " + string.Join(", ", grp.Key.list) + ": ");
                Console.WriteLine(grp.Count() + " rows");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lol database has one table "Test" with three rows. The output is this:

```
SELECT [t0].[Col1], [t0].[Col2]
FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [t0]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

Grouping by a, x: 2 rows
Grouping by a, y: 1 rows
```

I checked the queries, and it seems that linq-to-sql is smart enough not to generate sql for groupBy when it can't, so it will iterate through all rows of the table and then group them on the client.

**Edit:** minor additions for completion's sake, and the connection string now assumes Sql Server Express.

Comment: Ingenious, but I couldn't get it working ... I'm not sure why.  As is, the "Props.Equals" method returns true always in my test case; it seemed to be comparing the Linq expressions rather than the evaluations.  Don't you need to use "Expression.Compile()" somewhere in there?

Comment: Well `GroupBy` organises `Props` into a hash table, so `Props.Equals` will only be called for objects for which `Props.GetHashCode` return equal values, which means that they are most likely equal already. So by itself, `Props.Equals` always returning true is hardly a problem. You also don't need `Expressions` anywhere in the code, since the whole grouping happens on the client and generated sql is a simple `select` from a table. I also tried it with SQL Server Express with the identical results.